# APK signed with a different APK files of the previous certificate

Tags: android, certificate, apk, keystore, signed

I'm trying to update an application on the play store and it returns an error:

> You uploaded an APK signed with a different APK files of the previous certificate. You must use the same certificate. Your APK are signed with a digital certificate that includes the fingerprint
>   [SHA1: 8B: FF: 30: 3B: 2A: 02: 3E: DD: 73: EE: 3B: 5F: 3A: C8: C1: B3: 72: F8]
>   While the certificate that you used to sign the APK you uploaded has the fingerprint
>   [SHA1: B3: 91: 7C: 1B: AF: 1D: 29: 64: 30: E8: 11: 9C: E6: 30: E2: B9: 48: AB]

I formatted my pc and reinstall Android Studio.
I remember the name of my keystore, the alias, and passwords, but I had to create them again.

I read that if you were losing the key you could not use another. I don't understand becouse I don't forget the names or passwords, anyway lost the possibility to update my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't make a difference unfortunately. If you lost the keystore you initially created while building your final application, you cannot update the application on the google play store anymore :(

It happened to me last month, so I had to create a new application with different package name (because you cannot have 2 applications with same package name under **one** google developer account).

Comment: uh, so bad, instead with applications in eclipse I haven't had the same problem :(

Comment: So I should keep a copy of the file that is generated in C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_79 \ jre \ bin?

Comment: @PabloVillar, Keep your signed certificate in any safer place which will not be affected by formatting pc.

Comment: yeah, i learned the hard way, i now immediatley upload it to google drive - safest option